# A query executing in PhpMySQL, but not in Zend_Framework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I have a pretty big query, that is generated in in a script, to create something like a view. For an application.

Here is the query that is being generated:

```
    SELECT * , if((SELECT `formId` from `ssp_mail_templates` WHERE `templateType`='boss'
 AND `templateIsConfirmation`='0' AND `formId`=`id`) IS NULL,0,1) as bossTemplate , 
if((SELECT `formId` from `ssp_mail_templates` WHERE `templateType`='user' AND 
`templateIsConfirmation`='0' AND `formId`=`id`) IS NULL,0,1) as userTemplate , if((SELECT 
`formId` from `ssp_mail_templates` WHERE `templateType`='superuser' AND 
`templateIsConfirmation`='0' AND `formId`=`id`) IS NULL,0,1) as superuserTemplate , 
if((SELECT `formId` from `ssp_mail_templates` WHERE `templateType`='boss' AND 
`templateIsConfirmation`='1' AND `formId`=`id`) IS NULL,0,1) as bossConfirmation , 
if((SELECT `formId` from `ssp_mail_templates` WHERE `templateType`='user' AND 
`templateIsConfirmation`='1' AND `formId`=`id`) IS NULL,0,1) as userConfirmation , 
if((SELECT `formId` from `ssp_mail_templates` WHERE `templateType`='superuser' AND 
`templateIsConfirmation`='1' AND `formId`=`id`) IS NULL,0,1) as superuserConfirmation FROM
 `ssp_form`
```

And here is the code, that is generating it:

```
$valueArray = array('boss', 'user', 'superuser');
        $selectString = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i ++) {
            $type="Template";
            if($i==1){
                $type="Confirmation";
            }
            foreach ($valueArray as $value) {

                $selectString.=" , if((SELECT `formId` from `".$this->_templateName."` WHERE `templateType`='".$value."' AND `templateIsConfirmation`='".$i."' AND `formId`=`id`) IS NULL,0,1) as ".$value.$type;
            }
        }
        $sql="SELECT *".$selectString."  FROM `ssp_form` ";

        $forms = $this->fetchAll($sql)->toArray();
```

So, after doing this, PhpMySQL returns:

`Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0009 sec)`

While ZF returns

`Mysqli prepare error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

I believe that the answer should be fairly trivial, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you're using `fetchAll` with wrong arguments. The first argument should be either `Zend_Db_Table_Select` object or a string that goes into `WHERE` clause (which is empty in your case).

To make this query work, you need to use a different method:

```
$this->getAdapter()->query( $sql );
```

Apart from that, I'd suggest that you refactor your sql query. Having this many `SELECT` statements is killing readability if not performance.

Comment: @janis - its important to know why this works. Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::fetchAll() expects to the first param as 1 of 2 types: either a simple sting to be added as the where statement or an object of type Zend_Db_Table_Select. The getAdpter() method will return a Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract and Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::query() expects either an executable SQL statement or a Zend_Db_Select